# Error trying to get the url from an express static image with an action and a reducer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to get the url from an express static image
with an action and a reducer

my action:

```
import {FETCH_IMAGE_FAIL, FETCH_IMAGE_LOADING, FETCH_IMAGE_SUCESS} from './actionType';
import api from '../../../services/api';

const FetchImageSucess = data => ({
    type: FETCH_IMAGE_SUCESS,
    data
})

const FetchImageFailed = err => ({
    type: FETCH_IMAGE_FAIL,
    err
})

const FetchImageLoading = () => ({
    type: FETCH_IMAGE_LOADING
})

export default function getImages (imageUrl) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch(FetchImageLoading());
        // fetching data
        api.get(`/uploads/${imageUrl}`)
            .then( response => { console.log(response)})
            .catch( err => { dispatch(FetchImageFailed(err.message));});
    }
}
```

I send the name of the file that I have saved in an array by parameter to

```
const products = useSelector(state => state.data.filteredProducts);
const productTest = products[0];
if(productTest){
console.log(productTest.img)  
dispatch(getImage(productTest.img))
}

const imageUrl = useSelector(state => state.image);
```

my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    url: '',
    error: null
  };

  export default function fetchImageProduct(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case FETCH_IMAGE_LOADING:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: true
        };
      case FETCH_IMAGE_SUCESS:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error: null,
          url: action.data
        };
      case FETCH_IMAGE_FAIL:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error: action.error
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

basically i have this route on my express server:

> app.use ('/ uploads', express.static (path.resolve (__ dirname, '..',
>   'uploads')))

and on my front end I have the name of the saved image:

> productTest.img

but I have this error when trying to send and get the answer of my route:

```
Cannot read property 'closed' of undefined
```

basically i need to show the image of each respective product

Answer (score 0):

You have error which is not closely related to what you asked. Search in your code for `closed` property and you will see that `closed` is read from undefined object.

There will be something like `objectName.closed` where `objectName` is undefined, which is most common error in javascript development in my experience.

Check why `objectName` from my example is undefined and for the security of your code, you could make a check before reading a data from object to see if the object exist, something like.

```
if(objectName) {
console.log(objectName.closed);
}
```